# Google Analytics campaign data in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-analytics

I am trying to get the campaign data listed on my google analytics account in codeigniter. I have followed the google link:

[Analytics reporting API v4; PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php)

I have used totally the code from the above URL on my project, But I am not able to find the code to get the campaign data. Please help me to get the way that I can fetch the campaign data from google analytics.

Thanks

Here is my code -

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once FCPATH . '/vendor/autoload.php';

//session_start();

class Analytics extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * show the google analytics
     */
    function index() {
        $analytics = $this->initializeAnalytics();
        $response = $this->getReport($analytics);
        pr($response);
        $this->printResults($response);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
     *
     * @return An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
     */
    function initializeAnalytics() {
        // Use the developers console and download your service account
        // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
        // change the key file location if necessary.
        $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = FCPATH . 'xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx.json';
        // Create and configure a new client object.
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
        $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
        $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
        $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);
        return $analytics;
    }

    /**
     * Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
     *
     * @param service An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
     * @return The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
     */
    function getReport($analytics) {

        // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
        $VIEW_ID = "xxxxxxxx";

        // Create the DateRange object.
        $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
        $dateRange->setStartDate("30daysAgo");
        $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

        // Create the Metrics object.
        $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
        $sessions->setExpression("ga:transactions");
        $sessions->setAlias("campaign");

        // Create the ReportRequest object.
        $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
        $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
        $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
        $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

        $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
        $body->setReportRequests(array($request));
        return $analytics->reports->batchGet($body);
    }

    /**
     * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
     *
     * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
     */
    function printResults($reports) {
        for ($reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count($reports); $reportIndex++) {
            $report = $reports[$reportIndex];
            $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
            $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
            $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
            $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();
            for ($rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
                $row = $rows[$rowIndex];
                $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
                $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
                    print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
                }
                for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
                    $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
                    for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
                        $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
                        print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You've used the code, have you properly setup the API access? Can you post any logs/error codes?

Comment: @XTOTHEL I am not getting any error. I am not able to step ahead after the return $analytics->reports->batchGet($body);

Comment: @XTOTHELI also added the code which I have written in codeigniter. I need the campaign data from the google analytics

Comment: the service account is setup correctly, you have the service account credentials json file in the same directory as the code? You've given the service account access in GA to the property/view that you're trying to pull reports from?

Comment: @XTOTHEL json file path file is correct and also I am getting all the response like account id, client id and GA id and other information as well. But I am not be able to step ahead to fetch the campaign data.

Comment: Have you tried if "ga:sessions" work? Trying to figure out if the default quickstart works for you or not

Comment: @XTOTHEL Yes. deafult quickstart works for me. and also used pivotRequest as well, but no data getting fetched.

Comment: Do you actually have ecommerce enabled on the GA property as well?

Comment: @XTOTHEL It is enabled.